# Why does this function will not fire after select option is picked?

Tags: javascript, html

I am still a noob at this...and I have poured over this code snippet AND cannot find my error. I am aware `textarea` `REMARKSTEXTAREA` is omitted as I do not feel it is pertinent. Basically, this is a tool I'm developing for creating remarks for testing high cap data circuits.

```html
<!-- BEGIN TEST PATTERNS DROPDOWN MENU -->
<td style="text-align: center; width: 638px;">
  <select id="testingdropdownmenu">
    <option value="">MAKE A SELECTION</option>
    <option value="1">RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR 3 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR 3 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR 15 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR 15 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="2">RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR X SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR 30 SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR 30 SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="3">RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="4">RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="5">RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="6">RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="7">RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="8">RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 3-IN-24 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN 3-IN-24 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 3-IN-24 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN 3-IN-24 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value=" RAN MULTIPAT TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN MULTIPAT TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN MULTIPAT TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN MULTIPAT TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
  </select>
  <script>
    var mytextbox = document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA');
    var mydropdown = document.getElementById('testingdropdownmenu');
    mydropdown.onchange = function() if (mydropdown != null) {
      if (mydropdown.value == 1) {
        var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?");
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + "MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY...";
        this.value = "";
      } else if (mydropdown.value == 2) {
        var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY SECONDS DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?");
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY…";
        this.value = "";
      } else if (mydropdown.value == 3) {
        var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?");
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…";
        this.value = "";
      } else if (mydropdown.value == 4) {
        var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?");
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…";
        this.value = "";
      } else if (mydropdown.value == 5) {
        var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?");
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…";
        this.value = "";
      } else if (mydropdown.value == 6) {
        var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?");
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…";
        this.value = "";
      } else if (mydropdown.value == 7) {
        var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?");
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…";
        this.value = "";
      } else if (mydropdown.value == 8) {
        var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?");
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…";
        this.value = "";
      } else {
        mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " " + mydropdown + "...";
        this.value = "";
      }
    }
    }
    }
  </script>
</td>
<!-- END TESTING PATTERNS MENU -->
```

Comment: Check your developer tools console for errors

Comment: Syntax error near `function()if (mydropdown != null) {`. Check your console for details.

Comment: ^ I'd recommend looking through console, then you'll see the mass amounts of errors being raised..

Comment: `mass amounts of errors` = there are TWO errors in the code. 1 - `function()if (mydropdown != null) {` should be `function() { if (mydropdown != null) {` - and there's one too many `}` at the end of the script ...

Answer (score 1):

Your if clause opening and closing braces are not matching.

Replace script code with attached code, It should work fine.

```
       <script>
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('testingdropdownmenu');
mydropdown.onchange = function(){if (mydropdown != null) {
if (mydropdown.value == 1) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + "MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY..."; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 2) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY SECONDS DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 3) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 4) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 5) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 6) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 7) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 8) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else {
mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " " + mydropdown + "..."; this.value = "";}
}
}

      </script>
```

Comment: i keep getting the followig in the textarea when ran "[object HTMLSelectElement]..."... any clue?

Comment: Please provide complete page source, So that it will be easy to debug,

Answer (score 0):

```js
var mytextbox = document.getElementById('REMARKSTEXTAREA');
var mydropdown = document.getElementById('testingdropdownmenu');
mydropdown.onchange = function(){if (mydropdown != null) {
if (mydropdown.value == 1) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + "MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY..."; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 2) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY SECONDS DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 3) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 4) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 5) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 6) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 7) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else if (mydropdown.value == 8) {
var TIME = prompt("HOW MANY MINUTES DID YOU RUN THE TEST PATTERN FOR?"); mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR " + TIME + " MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…"; this.value = "";}
else {
mytextbox.value = mytextbox.value + " " + mydropdown + "..."; this.value = "";}
}
}
```

```html
<!-- BEGIN TEST PATTERNS DROPDOWN MENU -->
<td style="text-align: center; width: 638px;">
  <select id="testingdropdownmenu">
    <option value="">MAKE A SELECTION</option>
    <option value="1">RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR 3 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR 3 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR 15 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN FOR 15 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN QRSS TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="2">RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR X SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR 30 SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN FOR 30 SECONDS AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN ALL ZEROES TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="3">RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN T-DALY TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="4">RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN 1:8 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="5">RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN 1:7 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="6">RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN 2-IN-8 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="7">RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN BRIDGETAP TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value="8">RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR X MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN ALL ONES TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 3-IN-24 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN 3-IN-24 TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN 3-IN-24 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN 3-IN-24 TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
    <option value=" RAN MULTIPAT TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY… ">RAN MULTIPAT TEST PATTERN FOR 5 MINUTES AND TESTING OKAY…</option>
    <option value=" RAN MULTIPAT TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…">RAN MULTIPAT TEST PATTERN AND FINDING ERRORS…</option>
  </select>
</td>
```

Comment: Thanks guys... I was able to put something together that did the job with your help. MUCH APPRECIATED!!!!